# Installation of newer versions of MEEP

Tags: 14.04, apt, meep

In my laptop when I issue `sudo apt-get install meep-mpi-default`, it installs 1.3 version of MEEP. Everything is fine till now.
My laptop has *Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, codename Xenial*.

When I run same command on a workstation, it installs 1.2 version of MEEP. But I need 1.3 on the workstation.
Workstation has *Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, codename Trusty*.

`sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` on the Workstation are not helping. In the Software and Update application, every box is also checked in.

Comment: The latest **MEEP** version is 1.3. I wonder how you get version 3...

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I messed up with the numbers.

Comment: Does it have to do with the link of repositories in the software and update application.

Comment: I will answer ASAP...

Answer (score 1):

If there is no MEEP version in the official repository then you can consider installing it from source as given:

1. To prevent the case if anything goes wrong, we have to replace
   `make  install` with `checkinstall`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
2. Dependencies: In a window of the terminal we execute:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libtool* mpich-dev* lapack* guile-2.0 guile-2.0-dev readline-dev fftw3-* paraview hdf5-* gcc-c++ scalapack-* paraview*
   ```
3. Variable Environments: In a window of the terminal we execute:

   ```
   gedit .bashrc
   ```

   You can use other text editors if you like. Move to the last line and finish here:

   ```
   LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -lm" export LDFLAGS
   CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" export CPPFLAGS
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   PATH=/lib64/mpich/bin:$PATH export PATH
   ```

   Make directory `t` and enter there:

   ```
   mkdir t
   cd t
   ```
4. Load, Compile and Set FFTW Library with Support of MPI.
   This library was already set at a stage 1, but the hdf5 library for some reason works not correctly. Therefore it is necessary to compile and set it from source codes:

   For this purpose, in a window of the terminal we execute:

   ```
   wget http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/hdf5-1.8.14.tar.gz
   tar -xf hdf5-1.8.14.tar.gz
   cd hdf5-1.8.14
   CC=mpicc CXX=mpicxx F77=mpif77 ./configure –-enable-parallel –prefix=/usr/local
   make -j4
   sudo checkinstall
   cd ..
   ```
5. Libctl library: In the same place we execute:

   ```
   wget http://ab-initio.mit.edu/libctl/libctl-3.2.2.tar.gz
   tar -xf libctl-3.2.2.tar.gz
   cd libctl-3.2.2
   CC=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc CXX=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx F77=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpif77 ./configure
   make -j4
   sudo checkinstall
   cd ..
   ```
6. MPB: We compile and set without support of MPI and OpenMP:

   ```
   wget http://ab-initio.mit.edu/mpb/mpb-1.5.tar.gz
   tar -xf mpb-1.5.tar.gz
   cd mpb-1.5/
   CC=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc CXX=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx F77=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpif77 ./configure
   make -j4 
   sudo checkinstall
   make distclean
   ```

   With support of MPI and OpenMP:

   ```
   CC=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc CXX=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx F77=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpif77 ./configure --with-mpi --with-openmp
   make -j4 
   sudo checkinstall
   cd ..
   ```
7. Harminv. Execute:

   ```
   wget http://ab-initio.mit.edu/harminv/harminv-1.4.tar.gz
   tar -xf harminv-1.4.tar.gz
   cd harminv-1.4/
   CC=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc CXX=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx F77=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpif77 ./configure
   make
   sudo checkinstall
   cd ..
   ```
8. MEEP. Without support of MPI and OpenMP:

   ```
   wget http://ab-initio.mit.edu/meep/meep-1.3.tar.gz
   tar -xf meep-1.3.tar.gz
   cd meep-1.3/
   CC=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc CXX=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx F77=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpif77 ./configure
   make -j4
   sudo checkinstall
   make distclean
   ```

   With support of MPI and OpenMP:

   ```
   CC=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc CXX=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx F77=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpif77 ./configure --with-mpi
   make -j4
   sudo checkinstall
   ```
9. h5utils. The MPB and MEEP programs save results of calculations in files with expansion .h5. 
   Note: *This packet (h5utils) comprises a set of programs for work with h5-files, such as h5topng (for conversion of h5-files to the graphic png format), h5tovtk (conversion to the vtk format convenient for display by means of the Paraview program) and h5totxt (conversion to a text format). If not to set and to use these programs, then many results of calculation will be simply unavailable to viewing.*

   ```
   wget http://ab-initio.mit.edu/h5utils/h5utils-1.12.1.tar.gz
   tar -xf http://ab-initio.mit.edu/h5utils/h5utils-1.12.1.tar.gz
   cd h5utils-1.12.1
   CC=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicc CXX=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpicxx F77=/lib64/mpich/bin/mpif77 ./configure
   make -j4 
   sudo checkinstall
   cd ..
   ```

   If it happened so that command execution "make - j4" was interrupted with an error of" [writepng.o] of Error 1", then instead of the last three commands we execute:

   ```
   make h5totxt
   make h5tovtk
   sudo mv h5tovtk /usr/local/bin/
   sudo mv h5totxt /usr/local/bin/
   cd ..
   ```

For more information, see [this](https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Download/).

[Source](http://geek-mag.com/posts/248514/)

Comment: You should use `checkinstall` instead of `make install` where possible to be able to remove such software easily. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

Comment: Used `checkinstall` instead of `make install`.